# Is it possible to schedule cron tasks in mysql?

Tags: mysql, cron

I'm curious if there's a mysql built-in mechanism for scheduling queries to run at given intervals or if I'm stuck having to use (tried and true) cron for this?
If I AM stuck, what's the command for having the command line execute the contents of a sql file?
as in...

```
//created file containing some sql query and put it in the file system
//cd over to that folder...
>mysql -u username -p'password' myDB ... now what?
```

but if there IS a way... where is it documented, I'm not seeing anything at the mysql doc site. Specifically, I need something to run every night at midnight.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for event schedulers in mysql. If yes please look at the following link 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about inbuilt, but if you end up using cron, this is the command:

```
>mysql -u username -p'password' myDB < filename.sql
```

Comment: cool, thanks. I'm holding out for the *preferred  answer before I give you the green:)

Answer (score 1):

You can run arbitrary batch file with commands using syntax

```
mysql < batch-file
```

Some information on how to do this and more elaborate syntax is available here: [MySQL Reference Manual: Using mysql in Batch Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html)